# Transform parsed percentage data into new array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Assume data parsed from a tsv like so:

```
tsvData.then(function(rawData) {

  var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
    return {year:+d.year, age3:+d.age3*100, age1:+d.age1*100, age2:+d.age2*100, age4:+d.age4*100, age5:+d.age5*100, age6:+d.age6*100, age7:+d.age7*100}
  });
```

And assume that we intend to create a square matrix representing these percentages (1 rect = 1%, each age group = different color):

```
var maxColumn = 10;

var colorMap = {
  0:"#003366",
  1:"#366092",
  2:"#4f81b9",
  3:"#95b3d7",
  4:"#b8cce4",
  5:"#e7eef8",
  6:"#f6d18b"
};

graphGroup.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data1)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return (i % maxColumn) * 30
    })
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return ~~((i / maxColumn) % maxColumn) * 30
    })
    .attr('width', 20)
    .attr('height', 20)
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      return colorMap[d];
    });
```

We would need some way to transform `data` so that it has 100 items, and those 100 items need to match the proportions of `data`. For simplicity let's just evaluate at `data[0]`. Here is my solution:

```
  var data1 = d3.range(100).map(function(d,i) {
    var age1 = data[0].age1;
    var age2 = data[0].age2;
    var age3 = data[0].age3;
    var age4 = data[0].age4;
    var age5 = data[0].age5;
    var age6 = data[0].age6;
    var age7 = data[0].age7;
    if (i<age1) {
      return 0;
    } else if (i>age1 && i<(age1+age2)) {
      return 1;
    } else if (i>(age1+age2) && i<(age1+age2+age3)) {
      return 2;
    } else if (i>(age1+age2+age3) && i<(age1+age2+age3+age4)) {
      return 3;
    } else if (i>(age1+age2+age3+age4) && i<(age1+age2+age3+age4+age5)) {
      return 4;
    } else if (i>(age1+age2+age3+age4+age5) && i<(age1+age2+age3+age4+age5+age6)) {
      return 5;
    } else if (i>(age1+age2+age3+age4+age5+age6) && i<(age1+age2+age3+age4+age5+age6+age7)) {
      return 6;
    }
  });
```

It *kind* of works, but it's not scalable at all, but I can't imagine how else one transforms the arrays. Just so we are clear, by transforming arrays I mean we start with:

```
data = [
   {'age1':33.66, 'age2':14.87, 'age3':18, 'age4':14, 'age5':11, 'age6':5, 'age7':3}
];
```

and end with:

```
data1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1...];
```

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

//var tsvData = d3.tsv('so-demo3.tsv');

var maxColumn = 10;

//tsvData.then(function(rawData) {
/*
  var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
    return {year:+d.year, age3:+d.age3*100, age1:+d.age1*100, age2:+d.age2*100, age4:+d.age4*100, age5:+d.age5*100, age6:+d.age6*100, age7:+d.age7*100}
  });
*/
var data = [
  {'age1':33.66, 'age2':14.87, 'age3':18, 'age4':14, 'age5':11, 'age6':5, 'age7':3}
];

  var data1 = d3.range(100).map(function(d,i) {
    var age1 = data[0].age1;
    var age2 = data[0].age2;
    var age3 = data[0].age3;
    var age4 = data[0].age4;
    var age5 = data[0].age5;
    var age6 = data[0].age6;
    var age7 = data[0].age7;
    if (i<age1) {
      return 0;
    } else if (i>age1 && i<(age1+age2)) {
      return 1;
    } else if (i>(age1+age2) && i<(age1+age2+age3)) {
      return 2;
    } else if (i>(age1+age2+age3) && i<(age1+age2+age3+age4)) {
      return 3;
    } else if (i>(age1+age2+age3+age4) && i<(age1+age2+age3+age4+age5)) {
      return 4;
    } else if (i>(age1+age2+age3+age4+age5) && i<(age1+age2+age3+age4+age5+age6)) {
      return 5;
    } else if (i>(age1+age2+age3+age4+age5+age6) && i<(age1+age2+age3+age4+age5+age6+age7)) {
      return 6;
    }
  });

var colorMap = {
  0:"#003366",
  1:"#366092",
  2:"#4f81b9",
  3:"#95b3d7",
  4:"#b8cce4",
  5:"#e7eef8",
  6:"#f6d18b"
};

graphGroup.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data1)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return (i % maxColumn) * 30
    })
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return ~~((i / maxColumn) % maxColumn) * 30
    })
    .attr('width', 20)
    .attr('height', 20)
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      return colorMap[d];
    });

//})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

### Question

Does d3 offer something more sublime than my brute force approach to achieve the desired array?

Comment: Do you always have exactly 7 age values as input? What exactly are you trying to visualize? Shouldn't the ages be sorted first or something like that? I understand what you are technically trying to do, but not sure on the general goal

Comment: @ErikReder Let's assume we always are dealing with 7 age groups, and yea, just to keep it simple, assume a square matrix, 10x10.

Comment: (Edited above) - so you're tring to kind of 'spread out' the ranges of the individual ages? What should that represent then? I think you would only see 'spans', but there's no relation to the age values anymore, right? Is that what you want to achieve?
If so, I guess I would suggest to sort (/order) the values first, take min/man as boundaries, calculate the discrepancies between the single values first, and then simply set these into proportion. Would be ~10 calculations then instead of 100, I think.

Comment: This sounds pretty much like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Like @ErikReder already asked: tell us more about what you are trying to achieve instead of trying to fix a potentially sub-optimal or flawed solution. Threshold scales or binning might work for you. It's hard to tell, though, unless you give us more details on your objectives.

Comment: Ok, I finally got it. The values represent percentages of certain ages, and those percentages should be represented in an x*x matrix. The transformation, however, from my point of view is a 1-dimensional thing, putting the values into discrete buckets. The visualization is 2-dimensional then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want to create a pictogram. If that's correct, this mix of `reduce` and `map` can easily create the individual arrays you want, regardless the number of properties in the datum object:

```
data.forEach(obj => {
  modifiedData.push(Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, _, i) =>
    acc.concat(d3.range(Math.round(obj["age" + (i + 1)])).map(() => i)), []))
});
```

Pay attention to the fact that, since you cannot guarantee the order of the properties in an object, the `reduce` uses the bracket notation with `"age" + index` to correctly set the numbers `0, 1, 2, etc..` to `age1, age2, age3, etc..`.

Here is the demo:

```js
const data = [{
  'age1': 33.66,
  'age2': 14.87,
  'age3': 18,
  'age4': 14,
  'age5': 11,
  'age6': 5,
  'age7': 3
}];

const modifiedData = [];

data.forEach(obj => {
  modifiedData.push(Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, _, i) =>
    acc.concat(d3.range(Math.round(obj["age" + (i + 1)])).map(() => i)), []))
});

console.log(modifiedData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

By the way, your current data sample does not sum 100.

Comment: Your snippet seems to work just fine, but when I tried to adapt this for the whole length of `data` by putting it in a for loop and iterating like `data[j].forEach(obj=>...)` but my console log had an error "data[j] is not a function" Surely `forEach()` can be called iteratively?

Comment: You got it wrong. Don't do `data[whatever]`, just do `data`. I made that code to iterate over all your data array, with all the objects inside it. The error you got is because `data[j]` is an **object**, not an array... `forEach` is an **array** method.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you. It's working now, just have the 100th square and the 1st square switched at some matrices. I'll double check the sums equal 100 but let me know if you have any other hunches.

Comment: You were right, it absolutely had to do with summing 100. In my snippet above, i just used quick/dirty data, but my actual data sums *exactly* 100. I have just double checked the accuracy, and still the problem persists. I'm guessing there is some kind of rounding / remainder issue where some matrices are getting extras while others are lack a square? It's only ever off by 1 square (some are 101, some are 99). Let me know if you can think of a way to address this.

Comment: You'll have to create your own math function to deal with the rounding. For instance, if you have `[4.5, 4.5, 1]` you have a perfect sum of 10. But if you round them with `Math.round`, you'll have a sum of 11 (that is, `[5, 5, 1]`). Since this out of the scope of this question I suggest you ask this as a new question (without the D3 tag, because this is only a math problem).

Comment: Agreed, there is no right or wrong in this case. Especially, given the small dataset, readability and clarity should have a hight priority, *but*... Nonetheless, can I just say, that my solution is at least twice as fast as yours :-) https://jsperf.com/create-pictogram-array/1 The optimized vanilla version—using for-loops—adds another 50 per cent to that. It just seems the new `Array.from()` and `Array.prototype.fill()` methods perform painfully bad. Just saying. @ArashHowaida

Comment: @altocumulus very interesting jasper. However, unlike your 3 versions (d3, vanilla and optimised), my version doesn't assume 7 properties in the object, it can deal with any number of properties (due to `Object.keys()`).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Plus, yours is robust and won't even hickup on the additional `year` property in OP's original data.

Answer (score 2):

There are obviously many solutions to your problem. However, since you explicitly asked for a D3 solution, this is my take on it:

```
                                                // STEPS 1-5:
const data1 = d3.merge(                         // 5. Merge all sub-array into one.
  d3.range(1,8)                                 // 1. For every age group 1-7...
    .map(d => d3.range(                         // 2. create an array...
                Math.round(data[0][`age${d}`])  // 3. given a length as per the age property...
              ).map(() => d-1)                  // 4. populated with the value from 2. 
    )
);
```

Have a look at the following snippet for a working demo:

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

//var tsvData = d3.tsv('so-demo3.tsv');

var maxColumn = 10;

//tsvData.then(function(rawData) {
/*
  var data = rawData.map(function(d) {
    return {year:+d.year, age3:+d.age3*100, age1:+d.age1*100, age2:+d.age2*100, age4:+d.age4*100, age5:+d.age5*100, age6:+d.age6*100, age7:+d.age7*100}
  });
*/
var data = [
  {'age1':33.66, 'age2':14.87, 'age3':18, 'age4':14, 'age5':11, 'age6':5, 'age7':3}
];

const data1 = d3.merge(                         // 5. Merge all sub-array into one.
  d3.range(1,8)                                 // 1. For every age group 1-7...
    .map(d => d3.range(                         // 2. create an array...
                Math.round(data[0][`age${d}`])  // 3. given a length as per the age property...
              ).map(() => d-1)                  // 4. populated with the value from 2. 
    )
);

var colorMap = {
  0:"#003366",
  1:"#366092",
  2:"#4f81b9",
  3:"#95b3d7",
  4:"#b8cce4",
  5:"#e7eef8",
  6:"#f6d18b"
};

graphGroup.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data1)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return (i % maxColumn) * 30
    })
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return ~~((i / maxColumn) % maxColumn) * 30
    })
    .attr('width', 20)
    .attr('height', 20)
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      return colorMap[d];
    });

//})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to represent the single values in the data array as discrete values in an a*a matrix.
So my suggestion (in pseudo-code) would be:

```
 Scale values so the total sum is a*a (in our case 10*10 = 100): 
 sumAge = age1 + age2 
 .... data.forEach(age1/sumAge*100) 

 Now paint the chart: 
counter = 0 
 data.forEach age
    ageCounter = 0;
  while agecounter < age
    ageCounter ++
    set color
  while counter < 100 
   counter ++ 
 draw rectangle at x,y 
 with x = 100 mod a
      y = 100 div a
```

You scale the values - you loop stepwise through each data item (to set the color), and have an inner loop that is executed as often as you need to draw squares.